# need to copy war file from local machine to amazon ec2 instances

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu, ssh, amazon-web-services

Hi I have created an amazon ec2 instance and now I need to deploy my java/j2ee based web app.
I have apache tomcat6 running. I am managing the server via ssh in terminal. I need to copy war files to the server through how do I do that. I am newbie kindly help me

Comment: Probably easiest to set up an ftp server on the instance. What kind of instance do you have?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 64 bit 10.10 linux instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [SCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Copy) an option? Or [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol)?

Comment: I am using ssh, I dont know much about Sftp

Comment: Well, you might try SFTP. You'd just need a client and server support. Try and ask Amazon what they provide (I assume you wan't to deploy there, don't you?)

Comment: I tried rsync I used this command rsync -avz filename.war instance_key.pem ubuntu@xx.xx.xxx.xx:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps and I also tried rync -avz filename.war ubuntu@xx.xx.xxx.xx:/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps from both remote terminal and local terminal but its not working I am getting an error which says permission denied (public key)